# bluetoothd: 100% CPU usage if keyboard turn off (standby)

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using raspbian (stretch) and a bluetooth keyboard with touchpad.

If the keyboard automatically turn off (standby) after a few minutes, one cpu core going up to 100% usage.
It's the process: "bluetoothd" and user: root.

If I turn on the keyboard again, the cpu usage is reduced to normal 0-1%.

Can you help me to fix this problem, please?

Best regards
Flo

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: oh, sorry... I'm using Raspbian (Stretch).